# How to make elements react to user input on page

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Trying to make this so if you select the yes option for the first question that the second question is then not visible. This is using PHP7 with Laravel Framework and Material Design Lite

```
        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="USDyes">
            <input type="radio" id="USDyes" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="1">
            <span class="mdl-radio__label">Yes</span>
        </label>
        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="USDno">
            <input type="radio" id="USDno" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="2">
            <span class="mdl-radio__label">No</span>
        </label>


        <h6>How Long Will the Data Be Retained?</h6>
        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="Ret1">
            <input type="radio" id="Ret1" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="1">
            <span class="mdl-radio__label">>1 Year</span>
        </label>
        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="Ret2">
            <input type="radio" id="Ret2" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="2">
            <span class="mdl-radio__label">1-3 Years</span>
        </label>
        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="Ret3">
            <input type="radio" id="Ret3" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="3">
            <span class="mdl-radio__label">3-5 Years</span>
        </label>
        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="Ret4">
            <input type="radio" id="Ret4" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="4" >
            <span class="mdl-radio__label">5+ Years</span>
        </label>
```

Comment: You need to use JavaScript for this, as you need to load both of the elements in the DOM

Comment: How would I go about that? Sorry, I've only ever used C++ and Java before

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two VERY DIFFERENT things. If you are new to web development, check: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470971

Comment: I know they are, just trying to figure out what you meant by loading the elements into the DOM via JavaScript. Sorry, I should have been more descriptive

Comment: It is the Document Object Model. Please read: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp Will post a solution in a bit...

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it did help you!

Comment: I'm still struggling with where to put it and how to implement jQuery, been doing lots of research and i'm honestly lost. I understand how to use the DOM and everything, I'm just lost as to how to implement js and jQuery in my code. Is there any way that you know what to do with that?

Comment: Sure... I'll edit my post. Give me a sec

Comment: Sounds good, thanks!

Comment: Open up index.html in your browser and it should work..

Comment: You're my hero, thanks!!!!!

Comment: I am glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index.html`:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
<body>
  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="USDyes">
    <input type="radio" id="USDyes" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="1">
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">Yes</span>
  </label>
  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="USDno">
    <input type="radio" id="USDno" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="2">
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">No</span>
  </label>

  <div class="data-question">
    <h6>How Long Will the Data Be Retained?</h6>
    <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="Ret1">
    <input type="radio" id="Ret1" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="1">
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">>1 Year</span>
    </label>
    <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="Ret2">
    <input type="radio" id="Ret2" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="2">
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">1-3 Years</span>
    </label>
    <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="Ret3">
    <input type="radio" id="Ret3" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="3">
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">3-5 Years</span>
    </label>
    <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="Ret4">
    <input type="radio" id="Ret4" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="4" >
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">5+ Years</span>
    </label>
  </div>

</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('input[type=radio][name=options]').change(function() {
      if($(this).val() == 1)
          $(".data-question").hide();
      else
          $(".data-question").show();
    });
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Please refer to my JSFiddle for a complete working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/reqr3gjs/

OR copy/paste the code above and open in your browser. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using only CSS without having to use javascript (for the example you have above).

```
<html>
 <head>
         <style>
          .conditional_form_part {
             display: none;
           }

          .conditional_form_part_activator:checked ~ .conditional_form_part {
             display: block;
            }
          </style>
  </head>
     <body>
          <input type="checkbox" id="USDyes" class="conditional_form_part_activator mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="1">
          <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="USDyes">Yes</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="USDno" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="2">
          <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="USDno">No</label>
          <div class="conditional_form_part">
                  <h6>How Long Will the Data Be Retained?</h6>
                  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="Ret1">
                     <input type="radio" id="Ret1" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="1">
                     <span class="mdl-radio__label">>1 Year</span>
                  </label>
                  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="Ret2">
                     <input type="radio" id="Ret2" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="2">
                     <span class="mdl-radio__label">1-3 Years</span>
                  </label>
                  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="Ret3">
                     <input type="radio" id="Ret3" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="3">
                     <span class="mdl-radio__label">3-5 Years</span>
                  </label>
                  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="Ret4">
                     <input type="radio" id="Ret4" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="4" >
                     <span class="mdl-radio__label">5+ Years</span>
                  </label>
          </div>
  </body>
```

This way if one is checked the other one will be hidden. This answer was taken from https://content.pivotal.io/blog/showing-and-hiding-conditional-html-without-javascript

Comment: I've edited my answer to match your example. This html will work as is with no JS required